# How to align items HStack to VStack SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have no one to ask. Please don't dislike me.

I am doing a tutorial project on SwiftUI

How to align everything like in the picture? (I've tried everything I know)

[image]

```
        VStack {
            HStack {
                CheckBoxView()
                Spacer()
                Text("Даю свое Согласие на обработку персональных данных")
                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            }
            .padding(3)
            
            HStack {
                CheckBoxView()
                Spacer()
                Text("Прошу предоставить мне займ, подлинность предоставленных данных подтверждаю, и с Информацией об условиях предостовления, использования, использования и возврата потребитеьского займа, c Общими условаиями договора потребительского займа и Соглашением об использовании АСП ознакомлен и полностью согласен")
                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            
            }
            .padding(3)
```

Comment: One question - one answer (because some of your questions can have no answer).

Comment: @Asperi Yes, I fixed everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use VStack alignment, HStack spacing, and Add Spacer() at last.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
        CheckBoxView()
        
        Text("Даю свое Согласие на обработку персональных данных")
            .font(.system(size: 10))
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        Spacer()
    }
    
    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
        CheckBoxView()
        
        Text("Даю свое Согласие на обработку персональных данных")
            .font(.system(size: 10))
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        Spacer()
    }
}
```